# What process returns the "(404) Not Found" error

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have a simple test application (C# console application) that does an HTTP GET to a .NET resource:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://ranger/roztest/Default.aspx");

                System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + " - " + sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + " - " + "An Exception has occured: " + ex.GetType().ToString() + " - " + ex.Message);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

If I execute the following command:

```
net stop w3svc
```

IIS will stop. The command line utility that I wrote will return a System.Net.WebException "(404) Not Found".

**If IIS is stopped, which process is returning that 404?**

Is it the svchost.exe that contained the IIS service?

Background Information:
I'm running that Default.aspx page under IIS 7 on Windows 7 (x64) Professional.

The WebException is being thrown on the "req.GetResponse()" line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More clues emerge:

Check out the following [post from Mike Volodarsky](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/10/16/Where-did-my-IIS7-server-go_3F00_-Troubleshooting-guide-for-_2200_server-not-found_2200_-errors.aspx):

> Starting with Windows 2003, IIS uses
>   the http.sys kernel driver to listen
>   for requests, and the W3SVC service to
>   configure it to listen for requests on
>   all binding endpoints associated with
>   your site.  On IIS7, the service doing
>   most of the work is now called WAS
>   (even though W3SVC is till needed).  A
>   configuration error can cause
>   WAS/W3SVC to fail to start a site, and
>   therefore http.sys will not receive
>   requests on its endpoints.  Also,
>   there is the off chance that the site
>   definition itself is missing, or the
>   site does not define the right
>   bindings.

And even a [tool to configure the http.sys driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184379.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe (if you truly are connecting to a server which is simply not responding) it might be the .NET network stack itself that is throwing the exception -- probably related to a connection timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure if a "server" process is running. It may be some some sort of kernel thread that is doing the "listening" on port 80. Check out the following pictures:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/hayworthfamily/3911114750/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/hayworthfamily/3911114768/

That is a couple of screen shots that I uploaded to flickr showing the output of TCPView. *Something* is listening on port 80 and returning that 404, it's just not IIS.